# Multiset container appears to stop sorting

Tags: c++, multiset

I would appreciate help debugging some strange behavior by a multiset container. Occasionally, the container appears to stop sorting. This is an infrequent error, apparent in only some simulations after a long time, and I'm short on ideas. (I'm an amateur programmer--suggestions of all kinds are welcome.)

My container is a `std::multiset` that holds `Event` structs:

```
typedef std::multiset< Event, std::less< Event > > EventPQ;
```

with the `Event` structs sorted by their `double time` members:

```
struct Event {

 public:
explicit Event(double t) : time(t), eventID(), hostID(), s() {}
Event(double t, int eid, int hid, int stype) : time(t), eventID( eid ), hostID( hid ), s(stype) {}

  bool operator < ( const Event & rhs ) const {
    return ( time < rhs.time );
  }

  double time;
  ...
};
```

The program iterates through periods of adding events with unordered times to `EventPQ currentEvents` and then pulling off events in order. Rarely, after some events have been added (with perfectly 'legal' times), events start getting executed out of order.

**What could make the events ever not get ordered properly? (Or what could mess up the iterator?)** I have checked that all the added event times are legitimate (i.e., all exceed the current simulation time), and I have also confirmed that the error does not occur because two events happen to get scheduled for the same time.

I'd love suggestions on how to work through this.

The code for executing and adding events is below for the curious:

```
  double t = 0.0;
  double nextTimeStep = t + EPID_DELTA_T;
  EventPQ::iterator eventIter = currentEvents.begin();

while ( t < EPID_SIM_LENGTH ) {

     // Add some events to currentEvents

     while ( ( *eventIter ).time < nextTimeStep ) { 

         Event thisEvent = *eventIter;
     t = thisEvent.time;
     executeEvent( thisEvent );
     eventCtr++;
     currentEvents.erase( eventIter );
     eventIter = currentEvents.begin();

  }

  t = nextTimeStep;
  nextTimeStep += EPID_DELTA_T;
}


void Simulation::addEvent( double et, int eid, int hid, int s ) {
  assert( currentEvents.find( Event(et) ) == currentEvents.end() );

  Event thisEvent( et, eid, hid, s ); 
  currentEvents.insert( thisEvent );
}
```

---

I should add that occasionally an event, when executed, will delete other events from `currentEvents`. This is done with

```
double oldRecTime = 10.0; // gets defined legitimately in simulation
EventPQ::iterator epqItr = currentEvents.find( Event(oldRecTime) );
assert( currentEvents.count( Event(oldRecTime) ) == 1 );
currentEvents.erase( epqItr );
```

*Even if this code looks okay, I'd like to know other ways I can examine what's going on--I'm currently using a lot of asserts() and cout << checks.*

Comment: Why is `oldRecTime` not assigned any value?

Comment: Why use a multiset when you go out of your way to prevent duplicates from being added?

Comment: @Andrey: I'm never sure how to synthesize code for questions here. I do define oldRecTime before searching for it in the simulation. (It's specifically the previously scheduled time to recover from an infection, and it's stored in a Host class. When an infection event occurs, I recalculate all the previously scheduled recovery times, deleting their corresponding events from currentEvents and adding the updated events.)

Comment: @Mark: I have these asserts to see how common duplicates are--so far, I haven't seen any--and I plan to convert to set if I can.

Comment: @Sarah, I'd suggest converting to `set` and check the return value of `insert`. The form of `insert` you're invoking returns `pair<iterator, bool>`. The pair's `second` member will tell you `true` if the value was inserted, `false` if the key already exists. i.e.: `assert(true == currentEvents(thisEvent).second)`

Comment: @Nathan. Thanks. Hadn't thought of this & will try it (though I think I found the problem, see above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simulation, where I have commented

```
// Add some events to currentEvents
```

events were being added to currentEvents. (Hope that was clear.) If an event was added that happened to belong at the top of the queue, I believe it messed up the iterator pointing to currentEvents.begin(). I reset the iterator immediately before the inner while loop, and things appear to work.

I will update this question if this turns out not to be the solution, or if there are other problems in what I have here.

Thanks to all those who commented; it helps me learn how I should be approaching these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your event processing cycle fails to check whether the queue is empty. Otherwise, everything looks fine (more or less).

But if you run out of events in your `currentEvents` queue, the behavior is undefined. It could probably manifest itself as something the appears as event being processed out of order.

In fact, some implementations of associative containers I saw represented them by "virtually circular" data structures, in a sense that if you ignore the end of the controlled sequence and continue to iterate, your iterator will emerge at the beginning of the sequence. Could it be that something like that is happening in your case?

Another question that immediately arises in connection with your code: what happens if the new event arrives into the queue with the `time` value that is smaller than the "current" time? I don't see any checks that would capture this situation in your code. Obviously, if this happens, i.e. if some events arrive "too late", they might easily get processed out of order regardless of how you implement it.

Comment: For brevity I did not include them here, but I do have asserts for currentEvents.size()>0. That is unfortunately not the problem.

Comment: I added asserts to confirm that the added times are indeed legitimate (i.e., greater than the current time). That doesn't seem to be the problem either. (Thanks for mentioning 'virtually circular' data structures--good to know about.)

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, I'd advise changing the `double` you're using as a key to some integer type instead. The key for a `set` or `multiset` requires a strict weak ordering -- and a `double` does *not* (normally) meet that requirement (nor does any other IEEE floating point type).

Comment: Thanks. Would I be cheating to make the integer key something like ceil(1000.0*time)? (I replied to Andrey on the other point; the simulation breaks if currentEvents.size == 0.) Could I test to see if strict weak ordering is the problem by defining some small number epsilon and asserting that times must differ by at least epsilon?

Comment: Multiplying by 1000 wouldn't really help (you're still left with the possibility of things like NaNs that don't compare meaningfully). Defining an Epsilon makes the situation worse (it breaks a strict weak ordering, even *without* things like NaNs).